# Prisma query fields where value is a string or ID

Tags: server, graphql, backend, prisma-graphql

Sorry, brand new to Prisma queries and trying to figure out the query language syntax.

Given the following call made from my GraphQL / Prisma backend, I'm looking to query `{parent: String}`. Anything non-`null` will work here, `String` isn't accepted, complains about wanting an object. So, it's not types. I also tried `{ parent_not: null }` with no luck. Sorry for the beginner question, can't find this in the docs.

Bonus points, I'll take any help I can get, but would like to know how to query by `ID` type values.

```
    const children = await ctx.db.query.comments(
      {
        where: { AND: [{ isPublic: true }, { parent: String }] },
        orderBy: 'createdAt_DESC'
      },
      info
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the schema prisma builds for you `graphql get-schema -p prisma`, this will give you clues into what's possible. In there, you'll find things like `id_in`, `id_not_in`, `id_contains` etc. You'll also find something like `parent_*` which will give you and idea what you can query by.

In this case, what you probably want to do is `{ parent_not_in: "" }`, but `{ parent_not: "" }` would probably work too.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I was looking for.